# Should this work?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to specialize a metafunction upon a type that has a function pointer as one of its parameters.  The code compiles just fine but it will simply not match the type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/mpl/bool.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/identity.hpp>

template < typename CONT, typename NAME, typename TYPE, TYPE (CONT::*getter)() const, void (CONT::*setter)(TYPE const&) >
struct metafield_fun {};

struct test_field {};

struct test
{
  int testing() const { return 5; }
  void testing(int const&) {}
};

template < typename T >
struct field_writable : boost::mpl::identity<T> {};

template < typename CONT, typename NAME, typename TYPE, TYPE (CONT::*getter)() const >
struct field_writable< metafield_fun<CONT,NAME,TYPE,getter,0> > : boost::mpl::false_
{};

typedef metafield_fun<test, test_field, int, &test::testing, 0> unwritable;

int main()
{
  std::cout << typeid(field_writable<unwritable>::type).name() << std::endl;

  std::cin.get();
}
```

Output is always the type passed in, never bool_.

Comment: It doesn't seem to compile here (`0` is not accepted for `void (CONT::*setter)(TYPE const&) `). (GCC 4.4.1.)

Comment: It does compile in Visual Studio. (Probably a missing `typename` VS is not very strict on that.)
What are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: @UncleBens: I don't believe all the standard conversions (e.g. here const integral 0 to pointer-type) apply to non-type template-parameters.

Comment: @UncleBens - Thanks.  I hadn't tried it on gcc.  Someone on the comp.lang.c++ group was telling me that conversion from 0 to pointer to member was ill-formed so was already the problem.  I meant to go read the cited chapter/verse myself but haven't had a chance.

Comment: @Charles - I expected it to match the specialization of field_writable and so the output would have been something like "struct boost::mpl::bool_<0>" in VS.  Instead, as you probably see, it matches the general and outputs the metafield type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a working alternative without the conversion problems mentioned in the comments:

```
struct rw_tag {};
struct ro_tag {};

template<typename CONT, typename NAME, typename TYPE,
         TYPE (CONT::*getter)() const, void (CONT::*setter)(TYPE const&)>
struct metafield_fun_rw : rw_tag {};

template<typename CONT, typename NAME, typename TYPE,
         TYPE (CONT::*getter)() const>
struct metafield_fun_ro : ro_tag {};

template<class T> struct field_writable 
  : boost::mpl::bool_< boost::is_base_of<rw_tag, T>::value >
// or just derive directly from: boost::is_base_of<rw_tag, T>::value
{};

typedef metafield_fun_ro<test, test_field, int, &test::testing> unwritable;
```

Alternatively `metafield_fun` could also `typedef` readwrite-/readonly-tags depending on its arguments and `field_writable` derive conditionally, say using `boost::mpl::if_`.

Comment: Yeah, this will obviously work.  I should have been more careful a month ago when I just tried passing 0 to the setter to see if it worked the first time I wanted to use that feature.  I had planned on making ro metafields but hadn't gotten to it and didn't want to modify a stable package if I could help it.